# pcl_ros Difference of Normals segmentation?

Tags: ros, pcl, perception-pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is Difference of Normals segmentation from the below PCL tutorial implemented in pcl_ros?

PCL tutorial:
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/dron_segmentation.php

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270096/pcl_ros----difference-of-normals-segmentation?/) by [chambana](https://answers.ros.org/users/28837/chambana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, it doesn't. Confirmed by looking at github: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/lunar-devel/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros
and by looking at pcl_nodelets.xml in the pcl_ros ROS directory, found by typing
`>>roscd pcl_ros`

---

Originally posted by [buckley.toby](https://answers.ros.org/users/30452/buckley.toby/) with karma: 116 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0